# Passing a function identifier as an rvalue reference and applying std::move() to it

Tags: c++, stdmove

Consider the following snippet

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using callback = std::function<double (double, double)>;


double sum (double a, double b) {
    return a + b;
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Shouldn't this leave sum() in an invalid state?
    auto c = std::move(sum);

    std::cout << c(4, 5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sum(4, 5) << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm converting `sum` to an rvalue reference, store that in `c`, and invoke both functions with no noticeable misbehaviors. Why is that? Shouldn't `std::move` leave `sum` in an invalid state?

Comment: it is mostly same as `std::move(42)`: `move` is pointless

Comment: I can't find any legitimate reference explaining this in more detail.

Comment: A little question, why do you use `callback` instead of `auto`? `auto c = std::move(sum);`

Comment: This question was taken out of context, i.e. the original problem applies to another code snippet I modified.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `std::move` does.  It cast the result into something that may be moved from, and if it were an unnamed temporary.  That allows an object that holds an allocated resource to transfer that resource without allocating a new one.  It doesn't do anything interesting for, say, an int or a function pointer.

Comment: A move operation leaves the argument in a *valid* (but unspecified) state, not an invalid one.  (In this case the argument, after conversion, is a prvalue so any such changes would not affect `sum`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You move a pointer to function, not function:

```
callback c = std::move(sum);
```

Usage of `std::move` is redundant here.